# Rolling join using dates in PySpark?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to do a join between two PySpark dataframes, joining on a key, however the date of the first table should always come after the date of the second table. As an example. We have two tables that we're trying to join:

Table 1:

```
    Date1    value1   key
13 Feb 2020    1       a
01 Mar 2020    2       a
31 Mar 2020    3       a
15 Apr 2020    4       a
```

Table 2:

```
    Date2    value2  key
10 Feb 2020    11     a
15 Mar 2020    22     a
```

After the join, the result should be something like this:

```
    Date1    value1 value2  key
13 Feb 2020    1      11     a
01 Mar 2020    2     null    a
31 Mar 2020    3      22     a
15 Apr 2020    4     null    a
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an interesting join. My approach is to join on the key first, select the earliest date, and do a self join after the earliest date is found.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

# Clean up date format first
df3 = df1.withColumn('Date1', F.to_date('Date1', 'dd MMM yyyy'))
df4 = df2.withColumn('Date2', F.to_date('Date2', 'dd MMM yyyy'))

result = (df3.join(df4, 'key')
             .filter('Date1 > Date2')
             .withColumn('rn', F.row_number().over(Window.partitionBy('Date2').orderBy('Date1')))
             .filter('rn = 1')
             .drop('key', 'rn', 'Date2')
             .join(df3, ['Date1', 'value1'], 'right')
         )

result.show()
+----------+------+------+---+
|Date1     |value1|value2|key|
+----------+------+------+---+
|2020-02-13|1     |11    |a  |
|2020-03-01|2     |null  |a  |
|2020-03-31|3     |22    |a  |
|2020-04-15|4     |null  |a  |
+----------+------+------+---+
```

Comment: This is very complicated... Is there any way we can avoid grouping by value2? The real case has many more columns and value2 is just an illustration here. Why are we grouping by value2?

Comment: @Ehrendil That's because we want to match the earliest Date1 that corresponds to each Date2/value2.

Comment: Thank you. My F module doesn't seem to have an array_min. This seems to be a newer feature. Anything I can do without it?

Comment: @Ehrendil I've cleaned up my answer. No more group by value2, and no more array_min. Let me know if it works!

Comment: Took a while to adapt it to my actual use case but this worked perfectly. Thank you! <3

Answer (score 1):

You can try window lag function, it's scala but python version will be similar.

```
// change col names for union all and add extra col to indentify dataset
val df1A = df1.toDF("Date","value","key").withColumn("df",lit(1))
val df2A = df2.toDF("Date","value","key").withColumn("df",lit(2))

import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

df1A.unionAll(df2A) 
.withColumn("value2",lag(array('value,'df),1) over Window.partitionBy('key).orderBy(to_date('Date,"dd MMM yyyy")))
.filter('df===1)
.withColumn("value2",when(element_at('value2,2)===2,element_at('value2,1)))
.drop("df")
.show
```

output:

```
+-----------+-----+---+------+
|       Date|value|key|value2|
+-----------+-----+---+------+
|13 Feb 2020|    1|  a|    11|
|01 Mar 2020|    2|  a|  null|
|31 Mar 2020|    3|  a|    22|
|15 Apr 2020|    4|  a|  null|
+-----------+-----+---+------+
```